# What are the pro/cons if I expose entities keys in url?

Tags: url, symfony, routes, seo

I know with symfony2 is very trivial get pretty urls through routing system and I love it. But  when the routes parameters are based only in slugs I've got to find by slug.

```
$em->getRepository('Bundle:Entity')->findOneBySlug($slug);
```

I thinking about combine both parameters like **stackoverflow** http://mysite.com/articles/234/the-title. Mantaining the slug parameter only for SEO proposes and find directly with the entity id (234).

```
$em->getRepository('Bundle:Entity')->find($id);
```

What are the pro / cons using this strategy. I'm right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go as you suggested and use both an unique identifier and a slug, because you do not have to worry about unique slugs this way.

But one thing you should is check if the slug is valid.
So do not use URLs like this: **/articles/{id}/{unchecked-slug}**, because if you do that you can reach the same article with an unlimited number of different/evil URLs, i.e. /articles/123/the-correct-title and /artcle/123/some-dirty-words.

So i would suggest using something like this:

```
$em->getRepository('Bundle:Entity')->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug, 'id' => $id);
```

I am not a SEO expert, but I do not think, that shorter URLs are THAT important, as long as it contains useful words, that may be part of a search.

Answer (score 1):

From a pure SEO perspective, you want to have a shorter URL since they tend to attract more clicks and are easier to share. However, catering to only SEO would be a mistake IMHO.

Adding a unique identifier to the string would be a smart thing to do, and would make things easier to lookup and maintain. I would suggest putting the unique identifier at the end of the URL string to maximize the "SEO effect".

Keywords in the URL might be a ranking signal, but really they drive up the CTR if the keywords found in the URL match the user's query. When that happens, the keywords in the URL become bolded in the Search Results Page (SERP). By putting the ID at the end of the URL, you're helping to ensure that the keywords in the slug have a better chance of appearing to the user, which means a better chance of being bolded, which hopefully leads to more CTR.

Here's what I would suggest:

http://example.com/articles/the-title-234

Answer (score 0):

No one has suggested it so far, so I'll offer what WordPress does. If there is already a permalink in the database that is identical to the one being supplied, you simply concatenate a counter at the end.

```
http://example.com/blog/my-article

becomes

http://example.com/blog/my-article-2

becomes

http://example.com/blog/my-article-3
```

The method eywu suggested is second best, but only because you still have the full ID in the permalink. No one wants to remember that, and it has no meaning to search engines.